# Customize Xah Fly Keys

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, customize

I am using [Xah Fly Keys](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/ergoemacs_vi_mode.html).

How should I change the function one of Xah Fly Keys key bindings calls?

For example when in Xah Fly Keys command mode `space c .` calls the `find-file` function but I would like it to call the `helm-find-files` function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of aminb on `freenode` `#emacs-beginners` and the [Xah Fly Keys customization documentation](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/xah-fly-keys_customization.html) I have got it working.

In my init file after requiring Xah Fly Keys I added:

`(define-key xah-fly-c-keymap (kbd ".") 'helm-find-files)`

which made it so that `space c .` calls  `helm-find-files`.

As another example:

`(define-key xah-fly-leader-key-map (kbd "a") 'helm-M-x)`

makes `space a` call `helm-M-x`.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out and posting a working solution!